# Is there a meaning for the word "cegon"?

Tags: synonyms

I came across this word, as in Cegonsoft, cegon+software.. what is cegon?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trade name, not an English "word"

Answer (score 3):

A bit of googling shows the origin:

http://www.cegonsoft.com/index.php?page=aboutus

> Cegon is a Dutch word meaning Never Ending, which implies that our service is unflinching. Cegonsoft with over a decade of proficiency and experience in the field of training and placement we have about 8 branches spread across Bangalore, Chennai, and Coimbatore.

which is not true. There is no such word as Cegon in any language let alone Dutch